# View Oracle Object Usage History

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We are doing a clean up of our database and we have some database objects which haven't been used for almost 5 years. So it's well overdue a clean.

Is there a way to see the number of times a view has been used and when the last time it was used?

```
    ObjName   | Num times used  | Last Used |
---------------------------------------------
    vw_PSEUDO |  23             | 13/06/2014
    vw_ABC123 |  9999           | 23/07/2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT   *
    FROM   V$SQLAREA
   WHERE   UPPER (SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%NAME_OF_YOUR_VIEW%'
ORDER BY   FIRST_LOAD_TIME DESC;
```

V$SQLAREA is a system view that stores all the queries launched, so if some entity has queried your view, you'll find records in V$SQLAREA with the name of your view.

The field FIRST_LOAD_TIME is a string that shows date and time when your view has been used.

This is to find the recent unused views of your Oracle user:

```
SELECT   ALFA.VIEW_NAME,
         (SELECT   COUNT ( * )
            FROM   V$SQLAREA
           WHERE   UPPER (SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%' || ALFA.VIEW_NAME || '%')
  FROM   USER_VIEWS ALFA;
```

This is to find the recent unused objects of your Oracle user, limiting the search to the first 100 objects (rownum <= 100):

```
  SELECT   ALFA.OBJECT_NAME,
           (SELECT   COUNT ( * )
              FROM   V$SQLAREA
             WHERE   UPPER (SQL_TEXT) LIKE '%' || ALFA.OBJECT_NAME || '%')
              COUNT
    FROM   USER_OBJECTS ALFA
   WHERE   ROWNUM <= 100
ORDER BY   COUNT DESC;
```

WARNING: in my system, on the 23rd of July 2014, the minimum FIRST_LOAD_TIME is:

```
select min(first_load_time) from v$sqlarea;

2014-06-14/19:29:33
```

So v$sqlarea in my system has a retention of about 39 days.

Please don't forget that APPARENTLY UNUSED tables can be used by nightly batches for database backup, so you can't find queries or statements in V$SQLAREA regarding backup tables, although these tables are used by night in order to backup the master tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try this first thing tomorrow. 
Regarding the apparently unused tables, don't worry we will use with caution. We have a spreadsheet with what each table is for, the data it contains and so on for views etc. This is just going to be a guide to flag things up which aren't used frequently (or at all) so we can then narrow down what we need to clean.

Comment: `V$SQLAREA` can provide useful information but it should not be treated like a time-based queue.  There's no telling how long queries will stay in the data dictionary.  In the example the word "retention" is misleading - it's extremely likely that many queries less than 39 days old are not in `V$SQLAREA` anymore.  Although "retention" does apply to AWR tables, such as `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT`.  But those tables will still not contain everything since not everything is sampled and makes it into AWR.